# Basic Switch Statement

Tags: c#

I have a simple question about the switch statement. I noticed so far that it can be written in two formats

I was just wondering what is the difference, if any, between the two, as they yield the same result.

The first being as follows:

```
switch(day)
{
    case 1:
        dayWord = "Monday";
        break;

    case 2:
        dayWord = "Tuesday";
        break;

    case 3:
        dayWord = "wednesday";
        break;

    case 4:
        dayWord = "Thursday";
        break;

    case 5:
        dayWord = "Friday";
        break;

    case 6:
        dayWord = "Saturday";
        break;

    case 7:
        dayWord = "Sunday";
        break;

    default:
        dayWord = "Invalid Day";
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine("\nYour value of {0} is equivalent to {1}", day, dayWord);
```

And the second being :

```
case 1:  
Console.Write("Monday \n");  
break;  
   
case 2:  
Console.Write("Tuesday \n");  
break;
```

Comment: The first assigns the "answer" to a variable dayWord. You can then do anything you want with it afterwards, such as printing to the screen, writing to a file, passing to another function, etc . The 2nd simply prints the result to the screen. This difference may become clearer as you get more experience.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeff. Therefore the first one would be the better format to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Example:

A variable named `dayWord` is used to store the string.

example:

If value of `day` equals `1`  then the string `"Monday"` will be assigned to the variable `dayWord`. The final line prints the values of the variables `day` and `dayWord` using `Console.writeLine()` function which prints the values of both variables on the console and returns a new line on the console (`\n`).

Second example:

Directly prints the string on the console without using any variable names to store it.

example:

When `day` equal `2` , the `Console.Write()` function prints the string `"Tuesday"` on the console and the `\n` returns a new line on the console.

Difference:

Console.write() writes the string given to it on the screen and stays on the same line.

Console.WriteLine() writes the string and returns the cursor to a new line on the screen.

method 1: uses a variable to store the names of the days of the week and then prints the variable.

method 2: Directly prints the name of the day without storing it in a variable.

Best Practice:

If you will need to re-use the string (name of the day) again somewhere else in the code, method 1 is the best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

The reason I asked is because I was doing a practice exercise and based on the question, method 1 is what I produced but when I checked the answer, they had method 2... So I was just wondering....."Why?"

Again, thank you for the clarification.